# Extra underlining in text elements in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, text, svg, mozilla

I have problem with   attribute in mozilla firefox. in opera and in google chrome text is showing in the center of svg but in mozilla is not.  y cordinate is working correctly but x cordinate misses.

http://awtest.alterway.info/    << this is our site link, please see it in google, opera and mozilla firefox and you will guess the difference. and if you know how to correct this problem, please help :)

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the unnecessary whitespace within the `<text>` elements. This is a Chrome bug, not supporting xml:space as Opera 12 displays the same as Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.  You can keep one, but not both, of:

- the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute
- or the spaces before and after the `<tspan>`.

If you want to keep the XML formatting/indenting, remove the `xml:space` attribute.

```
        <svg  version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 640 480">
        <circle fill="#05aabb"  cx="320" cy="240" r="126.5"/>
        <text x="255" y="260" font-family="Verdana" font-size="40" fill="white" style="text-decoration: underline;">
        <tspan x="255">WORK</tspan>
        </text>
        </svg>
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/h8b4jqxj/)

Also:

- the `enable-background` attribute is unnecessary.
- `padding` is meaningless in an SVG context.

Comment: it has worked in opera and google chrome, but in mozilla is a problem again. there is a black line under the text in circle.

Comment: http://awtest.alterway.info  << look this url in different browsers. in google and in opera it is OK, but in firefox and IE it has problems. when you see that url you will guess yourself.

Comment: The SVG text is inheriting the "text-decoration:underline" from the `<a>` that surrounds it.  Change the `<a>` links so that they have no underline.  See http://jsfiddle.net/32bejt8b/

Comment: thanks, it worked in mozilla too! but in IE :hover effect is not working.